# ¿Cuándo usar strtr vs str_replace?

Tags: string, php, str-replace

Hay veces que es difícil entender cuándo es preferible usar `strtr` y cuándo usar `str_replace`. Parece que es posible obtener el mismo resultado con cualquiera de ellas, aunque el orden en que los substrings son reemplazados está invertido. Por ejemplo:

```
echo strtr('test string', 'st', 'XY')."\n";
echo strtr('test string', array( 's' => 'X', 't' => 'Y', 'st' => 'Z' ))."\n";
echo str_replace(array('s', 't', 'st'), array('X', 'Y', 'Z'), 'test string')."\n";
echo str_replace(array('st', 't', 's'), array('Z', 'Y', 'X'), 'test string');
```

Entrega como salida:

```
YeXY XYring
YeZ Zring
YeXY XYring
YeZ Zring
```

Aparte de la sintaxis, ¿hay algún beneficio por usar una u otra? ¿Existen casos donde una no sería suficiente para obtener el resultado buscado?

*Pregunta original:*  
[When to use strtr vs str_replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177296/when-to-use-strtr-vs-str-replace)

Comment: No sabía que se podía agregar una pregunta y responder en ese mismo momento, que solo fue traducida del sitio en ingles, si se puede hacer esto voy a iniciar a hacer lo mismo...jeje

Comment: La traduje porque es una respuesta que escribí en el sitio en inglés, que obtuvo alta votación, por lo que supongo que ha sido útil a varias personas. Mejor compartirla acá en español. Y para responderla, al menos me basé en esta discusión en meta: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46/son-aceptables-las-traducciones-de-preguntas-de-stackoverflow-en-ingl%C3%A9s

Comment: Entonces voy a copiar también todas las preguntas que tuvieron alta votación y pasarlas a este sitio. =)

Comment: Mientras hayan sido respondidas por ti misma, no le veo problema. Sería bueno ver qué opina la comunidad de esto. Si a la mayoría no le gusta, retiro mi respuesta recién traducida.

Comment: @Elena, me gusta [esta respuesta de Monica](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270226/185667) sobre la fase private beta. Ahora mismo puedo, pero creo que el asunto merece ser copiado acá en Meta.es :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Nota de la traducción:**
[La pregunta original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8177296/677022) fue planteada por @andrewtweber y respondida por mí mismo en el sitio StackOverflow en inglés.

**Primera diferencia:**

Un ejemplo interesante de un comportamiento diferenciado entre `strtr` y `str_replace` se encuentra en la sección de comentarios del manual de PHP:

```
<?php
$arrFrom = array("1","2","3","B");
$arrTo = array("A","B","C","D");
$word = "ZBB2";
echo str_replace($arrFrom, $arrTo, $word);
?>
```

- El resultado esperable es: "ZDDB"
- Sin embargo, lo que se obtiene es: "ZDDD"
  (Porque a B le corresponde D según nuestro arreglo)

Para hacer que esto funcione como sería esperable, es mejor usar `strtr`:

```
<?php
$arr = array("1" => "A","2" => "B","3" => "C","B" => "D");
$word = "ZBB2";
echo strtr($word,$arr);
?>
```

- Lo que retorna: "ZDDB"

Esto quiere decir que `str_replace` emplea un enfoque más global a los reemplazos, mientras que `strtr` simplemente traduce los caracteres uno por uno.

---

**Otra diferencia:**

Dado el siguiente código: (tomado de [PHP String Replacement Speed Comparison](http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=175031.0)):

```
<?php
$text = "PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor";

$text_strtr = strtr($text
    , array("PHP" => "PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor"
        , "PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor" => "PHP"));
$text_str_replace = str_replace(array("PHP", "PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor")
    , array("PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor", "PHP")
    , $text);
var_dump($text_strtr);
var_dump($text_str_replace);
?>
```

Las líneas de texto resultantes serán:

> string(3) "PHP"
>   string(27) "PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor"

---

**La explicación principal:**

Las razones de este comportamiento son:

- **strtr**: ordena sus parámetros por largo, en orden descendiente, por lo que:

  1. le dará "más importancia" al más largo, y entonces éste será traducido dado que el texto principal es en sí mismo la llave más larga del arreglo de reemplazos.
  2. dado que todos los caracteres del texto principal ya han sido reemplazados, entonces ahí termina el proceso.
- **str_replace**: funciona en el orden en que fueron definidas las llaves, por lo tanto:

  1. encuentra la llave "PHP" en el texto principal y la reemplaza con: “PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor”, lo que da como resultado:

     > “PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor: Hypertext Preprocessor”.
  2. entonces encuentra la siguiente llave: “PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor” en el texto resultante del paso anterior, por lo que es reemplazado por "PHP", dando como resultado:

     > “PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor”.
  3. como no hay más llaves por revisar, el proceso de reemplazo termina ahí.

Comment: ¿Olvidaste marcarla como aceptada?

Answer (score 6):

Complementando la explicación de Nicolás, el resultado varia por el comportamiento de las funciones.

- **strtr** está hecha para remplazar caracteres, independientemente de la forma que utilices, y recorre la cadena principal caracter por caracter, cuando encuentra una coincidencia con los caracteres de busqueda, lo remplaza y pasa al siguiente caracter.
- **str_replace** está hecha para reemplazar subcadenas, sin importar la longitud de origen y destino, a diferencia de la anterior que deben ser caracteres individuales. Entonces por cada elemento a buscar se recorre toda la cadena principal, sustituye todas las coincidencias de esta, y luego se pasa a la siguiente subcadena... si vas al ejemplo de nicolas, "2" se remplaza en todos lados por "B", y en otra busqueda posterior se cambia "B" por "D", y por ser recorridos separados obtenemos "ZDDD" en lugar de "ZDDB".

---

Además de esto, los tiempos de respuesta, no sera muy notable con cadenas pequeñas, pero a mayor longitud mayor será el tiempo que le tomará a **str_replace**.

Supongamos que tenemos una cadena principal de 100 caracteres, y vayamos a buscar 10 caracteres:

- Con **str_replace**, se buscara cada carácter en los 100 principales, lo que dará en total mil búsquedas.
- Con **strtr**, al haber una coincidencia se ignora el resto de la búsqueda en ese carácter, terminando en menos de 10 búsquedas, y cada coincidencia hará que las búsquedas sean menores.

Entonces, si hay coincidencias con **strtr** se harán menos de las mil búsquedas, mientras que con **str_replace** siempre se harán las mil búsquedas, sin importar si hay o no coincidencias.

Comment: Para complementar la información de otra respuesta es mejor editarla o agregar un comentario para que el autor la edite.

Comment: Acabo de registrarme aquí, así que no puedo comentar :v

Comment: Cierto, no tomé en cuenta eso. Entonces hiciste bien en responder. Saludos.